# Are any of the Ubuntu/Ubuntu-based distros or Fedora flavors using the kernel that fixes the bug with some Samsung SATA SSDs?

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, ssd, samsung

I have a Samsung 870 EVO 1TB SSD that seems to disppear at random times when installing or attempting to use my OS.

It has happened on multiple different distros, but not on Windows. All SMART tests come back with great results.

I know there is a bug related to some Samsung SSDs that was supposedly fixed. I'm not sure if there are other bug reports, but here's the one I found: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=203475

If the answer to the question in the title is "no", is there a way to apply this fix before I've even had the chance to install a distro to disk?

I'm really only guessing that this might be the problem since it works perfectly fine in a Windows environment, and there aren't any worrisome SMART results.

Comment: That bug is a few months old. Are you sure you don't already have a kernel with the fix applied? What kernel version do you have (`uname -r`)?

Comment: ... or `uname -v` (because many kernels only show their ABI with `uname -r`, not the stable version they’re based on).

Answer (score 6):

The [main patch fixing the NCQ trim issue](https://lore.kernel.org/linux-ide/20210823095220.30157-1-hdegoede@redhat.com/T/) landed [in 5.15](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=8a6430ab9c9c87cb64c512e505e8690bbaee190b), and has been backported to stable kernels [5.14.11](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?id=8197b03c757dc5ae7a7ce138926a599e9599b1e8) and [5.13.19](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?id=e8d5567d9f6c5946dca0b17b43f101e0875ce5ac). So distributions with at least those kernels include the fix: Ubuntu 21.10, Fedora 34 and 35, and any derivatives. However I’m not sure whether their current installers include the fix, or if it’s only available as a post-installation update.

Even if your kernel doesn’t have the necessary patch, you can avoid the problem by booting with the `noncqtrim` kernel parameter; how to do that depends on the distribution you choose and its installer, see the distribution’s installation documentation for details.